# How to implement session that tied with user login in struts2?

Tags: session, authentication, struts2

I have this application flow with struts2:

1. Page_A.jsp contain form that can submit a data to ActionA class with method executeA
2. ActionA->executeA method stores data in a sesion with key "myKey"
3. ActionA return result to Page_B.jsp
4. Page_B.jsp contains form that can submit a data to ActionA class with method executeB
5. In ActionA->executeB method, it will get the submitted data from the "myKey" session

I found out there are two ways to set and get the data from session:

1. Using ActionContext

   > ```
   > // put the data into session
   > Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
   > session.put("myKey", data);
   >
   > // get the data from session
   > Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
   > data = (String[]) session.get("myKey");
   > ```
2. Using ServletActionContext

   > ```
   > // put the data into session
   > HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
   > HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   > session.setAttribute("myKey", data);
   >
   > // get the data from session
   > HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
   > HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   > data = (String[]) session.getAttribute("myKey");
   > ```

Between the two ways, which one is the better way? Or is there an alternative better way? (I prefer the simple way if there is)

Second thing, I want to make sure the session is tied with user login session. That means "myKey" session data for one user will be different from "myKey" session data from another user (the "myKey" session data will never get overwritten by "myKey" session data from another user).

For example:

1. User1 login
2. User1 goes to Page_A.jsp and submit the data and now he's in Page_B.jsp (now the "myKey" session contains data submitted by User1)
3. User2 login
4. User2 goes to Page_A.jsp and submit the data too
5. I'm worried if User1 do submit from Page_B.jsp, will the data from "myKey" still refer to original data that he submitted or he will get the data from User2 (because the "myKey" session data was replaced) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` if you are working in an interceptor because it does not have the DI the actions have, for an action on the other hand add the `SessionAware` interface and the session will be injected.

The injection method lowers coupling and makes it easier to test your actions.

Both the above assume you don't need the full HttpServletRequest interface (which has far more functionality than *just* as map of parameters): http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Should you need this interface then `ServletActionContext.getRequest();` is of course correct. Once again in the action you can lower coupling by using `ServletRequestAware` which will inject `HttpServletRequest` for you.

If you only need a property map then just use the methods which provide you with a map. Again this is because it's a lot easier to test and the intention is clear.

Sessions are unique, and they are maintained by the application server. For simplicity, when a user is using your application you can rest assured that there is a session.

Comment: Is it okay to use `ActionContext.getContext().getSession()` in action class? So did you mean the session is not global, right?

Comment: Session is per user, scoped to the user (global is a confusing term that does not work well with Java). There is nothing stopping you, it would work but when you have the SessionAware and ServletRequestAware interfaces you should try to use those.